# How to get rows fitting list of parameters in SQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have DB with some columns and I have N parameters. I need to get rows where columns have all N parameters in any column.

Example:

```
id  title           place     author
1  'Book Example1' 'shelves' 'John Johnson'
2  'Book Example2' 'library' 'John Johnson'
```

And parameters like `['shelves', 'John Johnson']` so output will be row with 1 id.

Can anyone help me with this? Have no idea how to do it by SQL

Comment: So, the parameters come in an array? Is the array of fixed length or variable length? How do you know which element corresponds to which column?

Comment: Where do your *parameters* come from ?

Comment: @TheImpaler Yes, In array. length is not fixed, i can get any number of parameters. I don't know if it corresponds or not. They can be in any place. For example, if i get [ 'John Johnson', 'shelves'] i have to get the same result.

Comment: @username How do you know which element correspond to each table column?

Comment: @wildplasser From textfield, then i put it in the query

Comment: @TheImpaler i don't know in fact. All of them are 100% strings except id.

Comment: If you don't know which element(s) correspond to which column(s), then you can either: 1) Have a gigantic non-optimized query that tries all possible combinations (factorial number of options), or 2) Implement full text search. I think the latter is more appropriate.

Comment: @TheImpaler full text search. Thank you didn't even know postgres has it. WIll try it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple alternative of full text search. Shape each row into a single text string and match it against the array of parameters (`'{shelves,John Johnson}'::text[]` in the illustration below) as regular expressions.

```sql
select * from the_table t 
 where t::text ~* all('{shelves,John Johnson}'::text[]);
```